# Unknown php syntax

Tags: php, cakephp, syntax

I've been hired to do a data entry job for a client who is no longer in contact with his web developers. Long story short I've tracked a misbehaving field through a slew of uncommented code down to this line:

```
<td><?= $contact['Contact']['sex']  == 'm' ? 'Male' : 'Female'; ?></td>.
```

I *think* it's in php, the file extension is ".ctp", bu I've not ever seen anything like it, and was wondering if anyone could help me out.

Comment: Help you out with what - what is going wrong exactly? The code is showing "Male" or "Female" depending on what `$contact['Contact']['sex']` contains.

Comment: What is the error or the problem with that line? (yes, it's php)

Comment: .ctp file extensions are used by CakePHP framework.

Comment: files can have ANY extension. You can specify any file in the web server config to process a file as php.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant my "error" is it's not giving me the behaviour I expect, and I really just wanted to know what the hell it was, as it doesn't look like any php I've ever seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It translates to this:

```
<td>
<?php if($contact['Contact']['sex']  == 'm'): ?>
   Male
<?php else: ?>
   Female
<?php endif ?>
</td>
```

But there is really nothing wrong with the line that is **actually** in your file.

Comment: Ah, I see, I think the line was meant to allow for a 'u' which would spit out "unknown". Is there an else if operator?

Comment: There is... But you do not have one in your code.

Comment: Sweet, I think the original dev left it out, what is the "else if" operator for this php syntax?

Comment: Something like this: `$contact['Contact']['sex']  == 'm' ? 'Male' : ($contact['Contact']['sex'] == 'u' ? 'Unknown' : 'Female');`

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to give me a hand, worked a charm =)

Comment: @user1812406 no problem, happy to help :-D

Comment: I would say there *is* something wrong: Don't use short tags. If you deploy on a server without short tags enabled nothing will work. Overall the line with short tags + ternary operator is horrible to read and considered as bad code style.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing syntaticaly wrong with that line. My guess would be the problem is caused by the fact that the `$contact` variable does not have the structure implied by the code's attempt to access it's data with `['Contact']['sex']]`. You will have to do some more debugging before anyone can help you further.